# Spring boot admin server cannot reach instances deployed in heroku

Tags: heroku, port, spring-boot-admin

I am using [spring-boot-admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) library. I have a spring boot admin client deployed in heroku.
The client is able to register itself to the admin-server and also sends back a managementUrl, healthUrl and a serviceUrl back to the server.

The problem is admin-client's actuator endpoints are inaccessible in heroku. The admin-server complains of

```
 Couldn't retrieve status for Instance(id=156385483, version=0, registration=Registration(name=spring-boot-application, managementUrl=http://example.heroku.com:23349/actuator, healthUrl=http://example.com:23349/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://example,heroku.com:23349/, source=http-api), registered=true, statusInfo=StatusInfo(status=UNKNOWN, details={}), statusTimestamp=2020-01-08T13:13:32.710Z, info=Info(values={}), endpoints=Endpoints(endpoints={health=Endpoint(id=health, url=http://example.heroku.com:23349/actuator/health)}), buildVersion=null, tags=Tags(values={}))
```

The admin-server and the client work fine when running in the local machine. Could it be a port issue with heroku which is inaccessible and denying the calls made by the server?

Answer (score 0):

There is a provision to configure management-url, service-url and health-url as per the [documentation](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/)

Hence changed them to reflect the public heroku url of my application instead of the auto generated urls(accessed via ports). Worked like a charm after the change.